# Issue generating a pdf with phantomjs when there is flexbox

Tags: phantomjs

**Does anyone know if generating a pdf with phantomjs works when a webpage uses flexbox ?**

I'm using the example here to generate a pdf and it works very nicely except for the components that use flexbox

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js?utm_content=bufferda3e0&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer

I've also tried to generate a pdf out of www.stackoverflow.com (which uses flexbox for some divs) and I get the same issue, pretty much the element with flexbox takes 100% of the width and prevents showing other divs in the same "row".

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS is very much outdated, can you migrate to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)? (is a node.js module with Chromium underneath)

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/pdf.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  // page.pdf() is currently supported only in headless mode.
  // @see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753118
  await page.pdf({
    path: 'hn.pdf',
    format: 'letter'
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```